# Can I access a NAS through a bridged connection?

Tags: networking, nas

I plan to buy a NAS, but I do not have access to the wireless router at my house (I'm renting a room). Can I connect the NAS to the ethernet port on my desktop, then create a network bridge between the ethernet and wireless adapter, and access it as I normally would if it were connected to the router?

I intend to connect to the NAS from other devices as well as the Desktop the NAS will be connected to.  Would this require more configuration than the simple bridge?

I suppose I can just pull out my own router and connect to that when I want to use the NAS, though being able to access the NAS from Internet would be nice...

Comment: Why do you need to create a bridge connection? Do you have other devices that will need to access NAS or only your desktop?

Answer (score 1):

Yes but you will have to use a "cross-over" cable.

You could also use a switch and manually assign the IP addresses

Comment: This is not necessarily true.  Almost all modern networking hardware is auto-sensing in that it can determine the type of cable connected to it and configure itself accordingly.